# Checking the CN of a certificate installed in the cert: PS drive and doing an if/else

Tags: powershell, certificate

So I'm trying to determine if a certificate is already installed, and then if not perform some actions.  This is what I'm doing programatically (I'm skipping the bulk of the IF part because it's huge) (and yes I know my formatting is terrible - I'm still learning that).  Let's assume the $product variable = Finance and the $swimlane variable = QA1.... (these are set way up in my script).  A valid CN here would be FinanceQA1.mycompany.mydomain.com under this pattern...

```
If ([bool](dir cert:\LocalMachine\My\ | ? { $_.subject -like "cn=$product$swimlane*" }) -eq "FALSE") 
{Write-Host "Certificate not installed..., preparing request..."}
Else {Write-Host "$product Certificate Already Installed,  Skiping..."}
```

It keeps coming back with the ELSE value, even though the cert:\LocalMachine\My\ PS store is totally empty (brand new server).   What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't compare to `"False"`.  Didn't Oisin just answer this issue today?  Weird.  I guess when it rains it pours.  :-)  Compare against `$false` instead.  Or more simply try this:

```
if (!(dir cert:\LocalMachine\My | ? {$_.subject -like "cn=$product$swimlane*"})) {
    ...
}
```